# Eating specifically fruit of shmitta

Tags: money, mitzvah, fruits, shmita

Is there an inyun to specifically eat fruits that have kedushas shvi'is? How much must a person go out of their way to buy such fruits? Let's say they cost more, how much more must they spend? Is this "mitzvah" of eating fruit of shmitta so strong that it's like any other mitzvah where a person could be required to spend more money?

Comment: see [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCUQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fetzion.org.il%2Fvbm%2Fenglish%2Farchive%2Fsheviit%2F12fruit.rtf&ei=G9GVVfqFDsu1-QGlhYGwAg&usg=AFQjCNEOzYtN6DwRFObQ3Lowdgi3ma3bJw&bvm=bv.96952980,d.cWw)

Comment: Lots of questions in one question...